# Make text readable by reparing a image

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I have a few pictures that contain some text. What is the best way to fix a low resolution photo, in order to make the text readable? I'm not an advanced user of photo editors, and I don't know any fancy tricks.

[image]

I'm running linux because I have a crappy laptop, and I can't use photoshop. Gimp is the only things that works for me, but a lot of things are similar to photoshop, so if you know anything, please let me know.

The only method that improved the picture by 1-2% was by sharpening the image, but it didn't make it readable.

Comment: No there is nothing you can do about this image.

Answer (score 0):

First, save a copy of the image to experiment with. ;)

Then you could try increasing the contrast, carefully.

I can't tell if the one you posted is the actual size of the image. If so, it's pretty bad. But if it's actually larger than this, you might have a chance.

Comment: That's the original picture. I'll try playing with the contrast and see the result

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a picture again? Or was that picture sent to you by someone else and you can't get another good shot?
Try taking pics of documents using [Office Lens](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.officelens&hl=en)
It takes a good quality photo with focus on making the text readable, adjusting the brightness and contrast automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I used CamScanner in Android to do some 'magic'. This is all i got:

[image]

The resolution of your image is like 72 dpi. No OCR software can operate at such low resolution. You need to take a picture with at least 300 dpi resolution in order to do an efficient OCR (optical character recognition). That means you need a 5 Mpix camera.

Comment: ... and no, just changing the dpi/ppi value of the existing image to 300 won't magically make it fixable :) The photo has to have the N inches * 300 dpi/ppi pixels in width and height from the start.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: Yes, of course. Hence the need for 5Mpix camera. Thanks for the subtle clarification.